# href属性によるリンクに飛ぶことができない

Tags: php, xampp

`D:/MyPortfolio/Training/public/index.php`をVSCodeで開きphpを書いています。
その中でaタグを使用し、`D:/MyPortfolio/Training/public/confirm.php`に移動するリンクを `<a href="confirm.php">confirmへ</a>`のように書き、クリックしてみたのですが404のエラーが出てしまいました。
`<a href="confirm.php">confirmへ</a>`の表記のみでページ遷移させるにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか。
回答よろしくお願い致します。

**試したこと**
`<a href="../public/confirm.php">confirmへ</a>`成功
一度上の階層に戻り、指定したら開くことができました。

**補足**
`DocumentRoot`は`MyPortfolio/Training`に設定しておりhttpd.confのファイルにおいてindex.phpを優先的に表示するような設定にしております。

index.phpをブラウザで表示している際のURLはlocalhostです。

Comment: 問題の現象があって、その原因が分からないのなら、貴方が気になった点だけではなく、他者がそれを調べられるように該当のphpソースとクライアントにロードされたhtml,cssの全体を提示してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 質問文章の中では表示されない記号などはコードブロックの形にすればソースとして表示されます。[Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: それからどんなソフトウェア構成・版数・拡張機能や設定でインストール・使用しているかの情報もあると良いかもしれません。[Visual Studio Code でPHPを開始するまでの手順](https://qiita.com/tfukumori/items/97a8f1ac6532612b004f), [【PHP】XAMPP環境でVisual Studio Codeのデバッグ機能が動かずに嵌った話と解決方法](https://dolphin-review.com/vscode-php-debug)

Comment: index.php をブラウザで表示している際、アドレス欄はどのような URL になっているか質問文に追記してみてください。

Comment: Xamppタグがありますが、アクセスはローカルホストではなくて、ファイルアクセスをしているのですか？

Comment: localhostと打てばindex.phpに飛ぶようになっています。のでローカルホストでしているモノだと思っています。